# (Async) execution out of a natively compiled stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, memory-optimized-tables

I have a natively compiled stored procedure and I would like to do an async execution of another stored procedure. The background is, that I need to store some staging data as fast as possible (in my natively compiled stored procedure) and I would like to call another stored procedure asynchronous to further process my data (but without "blocking" the current natively compiled stored procedure).

Does anybody know whether this is possible?

Here an example of what I want:

```
create procedure [Staging].[spProcessXXX]
with native_compilation, schemabinding, execute as owner
as 
begin atomic
with (transaction isolation level=snapshot, language=N'us_english')


    -- 1.

    -- do my performance-relevant stuff here


    -- 2.

    -- exec SP_XYZ (async, for example over SQL Job Agent or Service Broker)


end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible. Make the app issue the asynchronous call.

Alternative: If this was a non-native procedure you could use service broker. So create a wrapper procedure that is not natively compiled. That wrapper calls the native proc and can the use service broker.

Comment: I already assumed that it is not possible, but I still hoped maybe someone maybe knows a possible workaround or solution. Anyway, thanks for your reply.